# Site creation in MOSS server which has SSL enabled?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-services

Can one create sites/subsites in a sharepoint server (2010) using webservices if that server has SSL enabled? My web app is not SSL enabled.

Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create a site in SharePoint 2010 server from my site even though mine is not SSL enabled. The 401 - Unauthorized errors went away when I created a credentialcache object using my windows id/password/domain. Not a wise move in PROD environments, but enough to get the issue resolved for now.